# Extend inner class attributes in python

Tags: python, django

In my django application there are several apps which I activated AppConfig via apps.py files and i have one `BaseAppConfig` class:

```
class BaseAppConfig(AppConfig):
    launchpad = None

    def __init__(self, app_name, app_module):
        AppConfig.__init__(self, app_name, app_module)
        self.launchpad = self.Launchpad()

    class Launchpad:
        show = True
        icon = "fa fa-cogs"
```

i use this `BaseAppConfig` in my custom apps like:

```
class CustomerConfig(BaseAppConfig):
    name = 'customer'

    class Launchpad:
        icon = "fa fa-book"
```

and when i try to reach `show` attribute of `CustomerConfig` using `customer_config.launchpad.show` it returns `AttributeError`.

Python overrides all the inner class like new.

How can i achieve just extending the attributes of inner class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're overriding the `Launchpad` class. Therefore, it can't fall back and resolve to  `BaseAppConfig` as you want.

You would need to change your class to this in order to make it work,

```
class CustomerConfig(BaseAppConfig):
     name = 'customer'

    class Launchpad(BaseAppConfig.Launchpad):
        icon = "fa fa-book"
```

That way it has a reference to the base class `Launchpad` instance.

Comment: I think you should indent the Launchpad class